# How to mocka method to return the resulting object

Tags: junit, mockito

So I have a Manager-Dao that I would like to unit test

```
public Bill createBill(Order order){
   Bill bill = new Bill();
   [...] do stuff

   return dao.save(bill)
}
```

What I would like for the dao.save(bill) method just do nothing and return the created bill. Not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want [`returnsFirstArg`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/AdditionalAnswers.html#returnsFirstArg()).

```
when(dao.save(any(Bill.class))).thenAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg());
```

Answer (score -2):

Two ways come to mind:

1.) extend the DAO and overwrite the save method to do what you want.
2.) write an interface that the DAO fulfills, exchange the references to the DAO with references to the interface and then make your own "mocked" DAO to use in the unit tests that does what you want it to do.

The second one is more work, but seems cleaner to me personally.

Comment: Yeah, but then I would just be copying the content that is [...] do stuff. Which makes it unmaintainable. What I was hoping that I could find a method to just return whatever object is passed in "as is"